# Breaking connecting between features (Editor tool)

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, editing, features, vertices

I snapped a series of lines to a point (The ? symbol on the picture). Now, I am trying to unsnap them so I can connect them to their respective line I just created.

My question is simple. How do I that?  I looked everywhere online. Whenever I try editing the line vertices they move as one. If I delete the point everything else is deleted. I really don't want to the delete the lines and redo all the attributes associated with it.

[image]

Comment: How are you selecting the line vertices to edit? If you double-click a line, only vertices associated with that line should be editable unless you have some topological editing running. Since the lines appear to have different attributes, they don't appear to be actually connected in a way that would require a break, but there is the Split tool as well.

Comment: You might try turning off snapping as well, although that shouldn't really be causing your problem.

Comment: To follow on Chris W's comment, are you somehow selecting all those features?  In ArcMap if they are in the same folder you can edit all of them even though you chose one particular layer to edit.  Layers you don't want to edit could be made unselectable.  To add to recurvata's you might adjust your sticky move and snap tolerances in the Editor - Options - Editing Options or Editor - Snapping Options, at the scale you are doing the selecting and editing.   Lastly, try turning the point layer off or even removing it to edit the lines, or put the lines in a temp project just to edit.

Comment: Yeah, the split tool does the trick.  I'll just have to do one line at a time. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your screenshot it looks like you're editing a fiber network, so I assume you're using a geometric network.

You need to add the Geometric Network Editing toolbar

[image]

Highlight the line you want to disconnect from the geometric network and press the second button from the left (Disconnect). **You can only disconnect one feature at a time.** After you move it to where you want, be sure to use the first button from the left (Connect) to reconnect the feature to the geometric network.

Comment: Good to know I can use this tool as well.

Comment: @OzTellez Oh yeah buddy, add it to the arsenal.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes feature classes that participate in geometric networks or composite relationship classes in geodatabases tend to move and delete together during editing. Maybe check to see if your lines participate in a geometric network, or a composite relationship class? If so, try deleting the geometric network or the relationship class in question and attempt editing again. Also, be sure to write down the geometric network/relationship class properties before deleting, so you can re-create the network or relationship after you're done with your edits.

[About Editing Geometric Network Features (From ESRI)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/About_editing_geometric_network_features/002r00000015000000/)

[Relationship Class Properties (Also From ESRI)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//004t00000004000000)

Good Luck with this.